Array to string conversion in Laravel 11 Models
I am having a problem with my relationships in model using composite key. I am using the package Thiagoprz\CompositeKey\HasCompositeKey. If I am only using a single key for the relationships in models, I am not having a problem. I also want to ask too if what is the correct usage for the controllers. Here is my current controller
Here is so far what I got from debugging From PHP Tinker
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $crse_id = $request->input('crse_id');
            $crse_offer_nbr = $request->input('crse_offer_nbr');
            $strm = $request->input('strm');
            $session_code = $request->input('session_code');
            $class_section = $request->input('class_section');

            $classData = ClassTbl::with([
                'classChrstc',
                'institution:institution,descr', 
                'termTable:strm,descr',         
                'academicSubject:subject'     
            ])
            ->where('crse_id', $crse_id)
            ->where('crse_offer_nbr', $crse_offer_nbr)
            ->where('strm', $strm)
            ->where('session_code', $session_code)
            ->where('class_section', $class_section)
            ->first();

            if (!$classData) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Class data not found.'
                ], 404);
            }

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $classData,
                'message' => 'Class data retrieved successfully.'
            ]);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Failed to retrieve class data.',
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    public function classTbl()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ClassTbl::class, 'crse_id', 'crse_id')
            ->whereColumn('class_tbl.crse_offer_nbr', 'class_chrstcs.crse_offer_nbr')
            ->whereColumn('class_tbl.strm', 'class_chrstcs.strm')
            ->whereColumn('class_tbl.session_code', 'class_chrstcs.session_code')
            ->whereColumn('class_tbl.class_section', 'class_chrstcs.class_section');
    }

    public function classChrstc()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClassChrstc::class, 'crse_id', 'crse_id')
            ->whereColumn('class_chrstcs.crse_offer_nbr', 'class_tbl.crse_offer_nbr')
            ->whereColumn('class_chrstcs.strm', 'class_tbl.strm')
            ->whereColumn('class_chrstcs.session_code', 'class_tbl.session_code')
            ->whereColumn('class_chrstcs.class_section', 'class_tbl.class_section');
    }


As the error suggests, the relationship definition uses array_key_exists function behind the scene to check if the key (in this case composite key) exists in the array of foreign keys for the related table. The reason the single key works but not the composite key is because the single key returned is only one value which conforms to how array_key_exists method is defined in php. The composite key on the other hand, returns a multi-dimensional array strucure instead which when passed as an arguement to the array_key_exists method returns that error. You can give this article a read on how to use composite key in your Laravel project.

I was able to try the article's suggested package. https://github.com/thiagoprz/eloquent-composite-key. I just wanna ask if there is a documentation for this package? I am still getting the same error after implementing the syntax from the readme file of the package.
